# Javascript source files on JBoss have the wrong content-type/mime type?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am writing a JSP application and am deploying it to JBoss 5.0.  When I attempt to retrieve my CSS or Javascript files, JBoss returns the wrong Content-type for the file, so Firefox refuses to execute code supplied in them.  Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

   <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.example.TestServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/engine/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>
         /login.jsp
      </welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <jsp-config>
      <jsp-property-group>
         <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
         <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
         <is-xml>false</is-xml>
         <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
      </jsp-property-group>
   </jsp-config>

   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>css</extension>
      <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>js</extension>
      <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Using lynx to test the file download, I get the following:

host> lynx http://devbox:8080/TestServlet/js/main.js -head -dump

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=EA6FFF63B00F0B8C0C44F7A79BD368CF; Path=/jclaim
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 1778
Date: Sun, 24 May 2009 17:53:31 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer by changing the following:

```
  <jsp-property-group>
     <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

to be this, instead:

```
  <jsp-property-group>
     <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

As a beginner to JSP, I'm not sure what tutorial I picked up the previous example from, but it had led to no amount of frustration.

The lynx command now results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"11038-1243181792000"
Last-Modified: Sun, 24 May 2009 16:16:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 11038
Date: Sun, 24 May 2009 17:57:07 GMT
Connection: close
```

This applies to CSS as well.